# Ruby on Rails vs ASP.NET MVC 3 - Which is quicker to develop a website with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

I want to build websites as quickly as possible, from initial concept to deployed within a few days. For the purposes of rapid app development - I'm fine ignoring Unit tests.

Assuming all things being equal, is Ruby on Rails faster to build a web application than ASP.NET MVC 3? I'm not concerned about the time taken to learn Ruby on Rails, I just want to know whether it is faster to develop web apps with.

Real life experience or references would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use what you're comfortable with. It's like asking which one is faster a lambo or ferrari :)

Comment: Yeh "quicker" is ambiguous. If you asked about things like agility, testability, etc then there may be more definitive answers available.

Comment: Quicker meaning - if I was an expert at MVC and an expert at Ruby on Rails and I ignored unit tests, which would help me build and deploy a web app quickest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will develop speed with the one you use the most. 
Simple like that, everything is based on practice and training.

You should choose based on what makes you comfortable:

- Language (Ruby, C#)
- Development environment (Windows, Linux, Mac)
- Text Editor, IDE...

Edit:

Just by coincidence from an [ex-googler](http://rethrick.com/#waving-goodbye)

> In the short time I've been outside
>   Google I've created entire apps in
>   Java in the space of a single workday.
>   (Yes, you can program as quickly in
>   Java as in Ruby or Python, if you
>   understand your tools well.)

Comment: So true. One more thing that should be cosidered is the deployment requirements. Depending on your environment ASP.NET might be easier to deploy compared to RoR, or vice versa. Whatever you do please consider this because you would hate to build in app in one only to find out that deployment requirements cannot be properly met.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're "well experienced with ASP.NET", it will be faster for you to learn ASP.NET MVC 3.

ASP.NET MVC 3 is an extension to ASP.NET, so your learning curve will be shorter.

On the other hand, do you want to learn new, non-Microsoft skills? In that case, Ruby on Rails would be an excellent choice. It is mature, fun, fast, lots of support etc. And all of the cool kids are using it these days.

The other part of the answer: which platform will your employer prefer? Assuming you'll be part of a team, what will the team as a whole use?